# Roadrunner RPC call log

Tags: php, go, rpc, spiral, roadrunner

I want to call roadrunners RPC method log from PHP.

I have an instance of `Spriral\Goridge\RPC` in `$rpc` and it is connected to the running roadrunner rpc via TCP. On that RPC instance I execute the following call, where `$payload` is a normal string. also tried with php array or json string and tried different flags for the third argument (`Relay::PAYLOAD_RAW`, `Relay::PAYLOAD_CONTROL` etc.)

```php
$rpc->call('log', $payload);
```

but I always get this error message:

```
Spiral\Goridge\Exceptions\ServiceException: error 'rpc: service/method request ill-formed: log' on 'tcp://127.0.0.1:6001' in /var/www/vendor/spiral/goridge/src/RPC.php:123
```

I cannot find any documentation about it, but the log RPC method is there, just need to know how to format the `$payload` and if required which `$flags` to add as thrid argument.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `log` methods available in the RRv2 via RPC.